# How visitor will experience from asynchronous handler

Tags: asynchronous, httphandler

I have been learning the implementation of Asynchonous Http Handlers.

I would like to confirm my understanding.

From a visitor's perspective, they won't be able to tell the page is handled by synchronous handler or asynchronous handler. They still have to wait until IsCompleted return true, ie wait all process finished, to starting to view a page.

The only difference between sync and async http handlers is on the server side. Asynchronous Handler will free up the main thread processing other pages. Am I correct?

Say I have a process which is to write the visitors log, putting down their info such as IP and system info, using SQL. I want this process to be executed after the user got the page. Is it possible to implement this using synchronous handler? Or Is it even impossible to implement using asynchronous handler?
I would appreciate if anyone can provide some graphical reference about the server status and visitors' status to allow me to put the pictures together.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. Specially there is not difference to end user.
But remember scalability improves a lot, think when you have 1000+ simultaneous hits to your website, IIS has limited number of threads available for request processing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433(v=vs.100).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433(v=vs.100).aspx